# MySQL - How to join/union these two selects to make a single query?

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database, union

I have the following table on my DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `heartbeat` (
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IMEI` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `oil_electricity` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `gps_tracking` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `alarm_status` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `charge` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ACC` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `defense` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `voltage_level` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `gsm_signal` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `alarm` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `language` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1451 ;
```

I have two selects that I need to join the results together as one single query statement:

```
SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime`<="2014-07-16 12:00"
SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime` BETWEEN "2014-07-16 12:00" AND "2014-07-17 15:00"
```

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime`<="2014-07-16 12:00" JOIN (SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime` BETWEEN "2014-07-16 12:00" AND "2014-07-17 15:00")
or
SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime`<="2014-07-16 12:00" UNION (SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime` BETWEEN "2014-07-16 12:00" AND "2014-07-17 15:00")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a **`UNION ALL`** set operator in place of the `or` in your query, and wrap the separate SELECT in parens. (Note that the potential for the two queries to return the same row (if `datetime` is exactly, '2014-07-16 12:00', that will match the predicates in both queries. It's a bit curious... why this wouldn't be done with a single query, `datetime <= '2014-07-17 15:00'`; or with an `OR` in the predicate for the two `datetime` ranges (if they aren't always contiguous.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a UNION construct in sql implemented like so:

```
SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime`<="2014-07-16 12:00" JOIN (SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime` BETWEEN "2014-07-16 12:00" AND "2014-07-17 15:00")
UNION
SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime`<="2014-07-16 12:00" UNION (SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime` BETWEEN "2014-07-16 12:00" AND "2014-07-17 15:00")
```

Documentation is found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: A `UNION ALL` set operator would be more efficient, since it skips the extra work of identifying and removing duplicate rows.

Comment: You didn't open the parentheses on both statements. I suppose I should have just put both of them inside parentheses and it would work?

Answer (score 1):

In your create statement you have a problem with the primary key im assuming this is just a typo and should be 'code'.  as far as the question im unclear if you must use a join or union or if you just need the results that both of those queries would produce with just one query.  If the later is the case this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM heartbeat
WHERE IMEI='123456789012345' AND datetime <= '2014-07-17 15:00';
```

My reasoning for the single date statement is as follows you are looking for less than or equal to July 16 2014 12:00 in the first and between July 16, 2014 12:00 - July 17 2014 15:00 in the second which would be everything up to July 17, 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just a little change made it work.

Sorry to bother with such an easy question.

```
SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime`<="2014-07-16 12:00" ORDER BY `code` desc LIMIT 1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM heartbeat WHERE `IMEI`=123456789012345 AND `datetime` BETWEEN "2014-07-16 12:00" AND "2014-07-17 15:00"
```

EDIT: added `ORDER BY code desc LIMIT 1` to first query

Comment: Note that the `UNION` set operator will identify and remove duplicate rows from the set. If you don't need the database to do that extra work, use a **`UNION ALL`** set operator instead. (There's a potential for the two queries to return the same row, on that boundary `datetime`, the same row could be returned by both queries. To avoid that, change the first query to use a **`<`** comparator,  rather than a **`<=`**. (It's not clear why this same result couldn't be returned by a single `SELECT`.) To have the set ordered, wrap each SELECT in parens, and add an `ORDER BY` after the last paren.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that. Of course, I will just use `<` instead of `<=` and `UNION ALL` on the first query. I'm making 2 selects because I need exactly one row before the rows of the second select (I'm also adding `ORDER BY desc LIMIT 1` to the end of it) but I don't know the exact time I should lower the first and I can't really handle the dates to modify it. Thank you.

Comment: If you are adding an `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` to either of the queries, you will want to _enclose_ each query in parens, and then combine with `UNION ALL`. To guarantee the order of the returned results, you'll need to also add an `ORDER BY` after the last paren. (Adding the `ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT ...` to the first query, that explains why you would want to use two queries. For peformance, consider adding an index ... `ON heartbeat(IMEI,datetime)`